# Excel column order from powerpivot

Tags: database, excel, powerpivot

How can I rearrange column order from powerpivot data model? Unchecking/checking `Preserve column sort/filter/layout` doesn't work.
For example in powerPivot I have something like this:

```
col1 | calculatedCol | col2
```

But in Excel table:

```
col1 | col2 | calculatedCol
```

Drag and drop columns in diagram view also doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can rearrange columns order in the Data View window itself by selecting a column and then dragging to the desired location. Doesn't it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Is your issue that the Data Model and your Excel table don't match? Have you tried adding the table again, or just rearrange the columns in Excel to match your Data Model?

Answer (score 0):

try to select the cell with the column header in the pivot table and horizontally drag it to its new position